# Setting React state Asynchronous - React useState hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I am trying to update 1 quote inside of an array of "quotes"

```js
const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);
const [quoteToUpdate, setQuoteToUpdate] = useState(initialValues);
```

When I click on a switch (checkbox) I set quoteToUpdate with the `quoteToUpdate` with the selected quote data, and update the switch from true to false or vice versa.

[image]

```js
const onCheckboxChange = async (e, selectedQuote) => {
  setQuoteToUpdate({...selectedQuote, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked});
};
```

The Problem I'm having is, right after I update the `quoteUpdate`, I need to send the updated object to the backend to update. But since React state is `sync`, the `quoteToUpdate` does not get updated instantly but instead queues up.

What I've tried:
I've tried putting the `onSubmit()` function inside a `useEffect` but it's clearly not working.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  onSubmit(quoteToUpdate);
}, [quoteToUpdate])
```

onSubmit looks like this:

```js
const onSubmit = (quoteToUpdate) => {
    axiosWithAuth().put('/quotes/' + quoteToUpdate.id, quoteToUpdate)
      .then((res) => {
        const updatedQuote = res.data;
        setQuotes(quotes.map(quote => (
          quote.id === updatedQuote.id ? {...quote, 'is_complete': updatedQuote.is_complete} : quote
          ))
        );

        const alertContent = `quote updated successfully.`;

        halfmoon.stickyAlerts = document.getElementsByClassName("sticky-alerts")[0]
        halfmoon.initStickyAlert({
        content: alertContent, alertType: "alert-success", title: "Successfully updated"
      })
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
}
```

Update:

It looks like upoon clicking the switch it send the previous value.
[image]

Comment: why does calling `onSubmit` in the effect not work for you? Do you get an error? is `onSubmit` called?

Comment: Oh, you know what, it looks like the way I'm updating the object inside the array is incorrect. `setQuotes(quotes.map(quote => (
          quote.id === updatedQuote.id ? {...quote, 'is_complete': updatedQuote.is_complete} : quote
          ))
        );`

Comment: Try this `setQuote((prev) => {return prev.map(quote => (quote.id === updatedQuote.id ?{...quote, 'is_complete': updatedQuote.is_complete} : quote ))})`

Comment: @VitaliyRayets the switch is still only updated after I press on it twice. hit once, switch stay still, hit again, switch moves

Comment: @VitaliyRayets I updated my post at the bottom

Comment: Solved, this was an issue in the backend, express wasn't sending the updated used.